# Why java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE114 field name is invalid occurs on AIX when Proguard is used?

Tags: java, proguard, aix

I have used Proguard on the jar file to obfuscate it. It works very well on Windows and Linux but when deployed on AIX it gives following error.

```
2019-06-29 13:09:12:192 [ERROR] [main:ID=1]:[null:-1] java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE114 field name is invalid; class=Messaging/broadcaster/OracleWriterMessageBroadcaster, offset=0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:718)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1169)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:742)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:601)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:766)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:747)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:257)
    at UniversalGprsClientService.ProcessMonitor.a(Unknown Source)
    at UniversalGprsClientService.ProcessMonitor.main(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code snippet where the error occurs:

```
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(sClassName);

        Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor();
        IMessageBroadcaster clsBroadcaster = (IMessageBroadcaster) cons.newInstance();
        clsBroadcaster.setAppSettings(clsAppSettings);
        clsBroadcaster.setProcessMonitor(clsMonitor);
        return clsBroadcaster;
```

I guess it could be solved by just hard coding the classes but it means loosing some flexibility it offers.

Comment: Use command `javap <classname>` to find out the field-names. Maybe the program is right, and some of them are invalid (eg `@#1001` would be an illegal identifier.)